# Removing the class name before calling a custom function?

Tags: asp.net

I have a function for getting a string to have only the first letter to be uppercase.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
    {
        // Check for empty string.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        // Return char and concat substring.
        return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1).ToLower();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
string MyName = "john";
string result = Class1.UppercaseFirst(MyName)

Result: "John"
```

Is it possible to remove the "Class1." before the call to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) then you can call it like `"john".UppercaseFirst();`

You just need to declare your class as static and change the signature to the following

```
public static string UppercaseFirst(this string s)
    {...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
  public static string UppercaseFirst(this string text)
  {
    // ..
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
string uppercase = "myText".UppercaseFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if you call the static method from inside the same `Class1`. If you call it from outside the class you'll need the `Class1` specifier.

However, if you make it an extension method in a static class, you can call it directly on all strings.